# (Linux/Ubuntu) Как настроить стрелки на определенные клавиши при зажатом Alt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура

Надоело постоянно сдвигать правую руку на стрелки каждый раз когда нужно перемещаться по коду. Есть идея для этого использовать к примеру клавиши IJKL при зажатом Alt, но вот как это все настроить даже не представляю. Сижу на Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Можно использовать `xdotool` и назначить горячие клавиши в *Меню - Параметры системы - Клавиатура - Комбинации клавиш - Дополнительные комбинации*.

[image: рис. 1]

Здесь надо добавить 4 кнопки соответственно:

```
xdotool keyup Ctrl key Up keydown Ctrl
xdotool keyup Ctrl key Left keydown Ctrl
xdotool keyup Ctrl key Down keydown Ctrl
xdotool keyup Ctrl key Right keydown Ctrl
```

И назначить им комбинации `Control + I`, `Control + J`, `Control + K`, `Control + L`

[image: рис. 2]

Корявый, конечно, вариант. Но раз уж ничего другого не предлагают...

**Вариант 2**

Использовать `xmodmap`:

```
$ cat > ~/.Xmodmap
keycode 37 = Mode_switch
keysym j = j J Left 
keysym l = l L Right
keysym i = i I Up
keysym k = k K Down
^C
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

`keycode 37` - это левый Control

Команду `$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` нужно поместить в автозагрузку.

Второй вариант считаю более правильным.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Добавил второй вариант, более качественный.